# Terminating Windows Service in case of exception in processing thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, windows-services, task-parallel-library

I'm developing a windows service application that uses TPL to start it's main processing task.

The processing task is a continuous while loop that once started, continues it's execution until a cancellation request from Windows Service infrastructure is issued.

The startup is implemented as follows:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
       continuousProcessingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => DoStuffInAWhileLoopUntilCancelled(cancellation), cancellation, 
                     TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
```

Question is, I want the service to be terminated if an unhanded exception occurs somewhere in the main task (in DoStuffInAWhileLoopUntilCancelled method).

To be more precise, I want the **service to be in a consistent state** when unhandled exception occurs in processing task. With the above snippet it will end up with the situation of a running windows service but with processing task terminated, which in my opinion is inconsistent.
In my understanding, consistent behavior would mean that a processing task/thread and parent service process are both running, or nothing is running.

I ended up with continuation approach, shutting down service process if the main processing thread has failed:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
    continuousProcessingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => DoStuffInAWhileLoopUntilCancelled(cancellation), cancellation, 
                 TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default)
    .ContinueWith(OnTaskCompleted);
    }

    void OnTaskCompleted(Task task)
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            if (task.Exception != null)
            {
                Service.EventLog.SafeWriteEntry(task.Exception.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
            // shut down the application
            System.Environment.Exit(-1);
        }
    }
```

But I'm not sure if this is a recommended approach here - System.Environment.Exit looks ugly (and breaks class isolation). Are there other options for handling termination of the main processing task in this pattern (first code snippet)?

**UPD1:**
Clarified the question above.

Comment: If this happens in service itself, why not just call Stop on service? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.stop.aspx

Comment: This app can run as a console process (for devs) and as a service (for prod). This is a good idea, thanks, I can try calling Stop instead on System.Environment.Exit. However now I understand that my question is slightly broader - how in general should I be handling unhanded exceptions in the main processing task...?

Comment: When you run in console application - just make it exit from the main method as usual. Don't use Environment.Exit (or FailFast etc) until it is absolutely necessary. If you encounter unhandled exception - your application should log, cleanup and gracefully exit. If that is a service that is always running - configure it to restart automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Basically, that's what I have with these services - they restart indefinitely based on service recovery actions. It looks like, what I have now (second code snippet) is pretty much it, with an exception of graceful exit (just needs replacing System.Environment.Exit). the argument from raidensan is that service should run contuniously, so I was wondering whether processing task restart should be done within already running service process... (this can be detected and done in continuation)

Comment: One option would be to rethrow the exception, which should result in the process terminating abnormally.  The potential advantage of doing it this way is that it should trigger Windows service failure handling, allowing you to configure the service to be automatically restarted on failure.

Comment: Yes, however exiting with a non-zero exit code should trigger the same, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know about "should", but in my experience it doesn't.

Comment: ... and as far as I can tell there is no requirement that a service process exit with code 0 if there *wasn't* an error.  It may be that some services always return a non-zero exit code, and treating them as having failed would break backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Since *expected behavior* of service is to run *continuously*, terminating service in case of exception might not be a good idea. If your app need to perform a certain task a few times, a console app would suffice.

A better approach is to handle exceptions properly(depending on context) and keep the service running. Please note: A running service does not necessarily mean it is performing some task. You can keep the service running and perform task only when needed.

**But**, if you need to instantly terminate service you can use [FailFast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The app has to perform continuous dispatching of work until request for stop is not sent to service. However, if exception arises (for example - database is inaccessible for a period of time) in the main dispatching task, the task terminates, but the service process keeps running (doing nothing, since main processing task is down). Broader question is - should I terminate the service, or should I try restarting the dispatching task, or should I do something else? :-/ As for FailFast - not sure if I need my reports to go to Microsoft :)

Comment: Keep  the service running and try restarting your task. Also, both FailSafe and Environment.Exit will terminate the service itself along with all sub-processes.